# Scala mongo driver custom codec for case classes

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

The scala-mongo-driver has a decent documentation for working with case classes. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.3/getting-started/quick-tour-case-classes/. 
In current situation my case class fields are Option[T] values. So the values can be either `None` or `Some(T)`.The default codec is now serializing 'None' values as null. But I want to exclude the key if its value is None. How can I obtain this behavior? From my research I think we need to write a custom Codec or Codec Provider for the case class instead of the default case class codec.

Comment: I think you should leave `None` values as `null` in Mongo documents. Otherwise you will have to take care of it in custom codecs for your case classes.

Comment: Ya I was thinking about the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an new macro helper since v2.1.0: `Macros.createCodecProviderIgnoreNone` where you can define that `None` values will be ignored from saving to the DB.

- [description of the bson-macros](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.3/bson/macros/)
- [scaladoc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.3/scaladoc/org/mongodb/scala/bson/codecs/Macros$.html)

Comment: Thanks. I have found this one in the docs but forgot to update here.:)